# Running virtual machine host and guest on a laptop/desktop

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost

I would like to create a portable system by installing a minimal virtual machine host on my laptop and on my desktop. I would then like to have the virtual machine guest on a USB memory stick that I can run on both the laptop and desktop (not at the same time). By moving the USB memory stick from one to the other I would have the same installation on whichever computer (desktop/laptop) I decide to use. Is this setup possible to create with Ubuntu? Where could I find further information about the setup?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with VirtualBox. When you create a virtual machine, you can choose where the files are saved, so you can save them on removable media. And on the other machine you can tell it to run the virtual machien stored on the removable media.

Actually, it may be preferable to create separate virtual machines on both systems, and store only the virtual disk file on removable media. Think of having two computers in two places and just carrying the hard drive.

Comment: Is it possible to create something more lightweight? For VirtualBox I would have to install a full blown operating system and VirtualBox. I would like to have a host with a smaller footprint, just the bare essentials that boots directly into the virtual machine.

Comment: @user148095 Please add all the necessary information to your question. From this comment it looks like you don't even need a virtual machine at all, just install an OS on the removable media...

Comment: I've already tried that but the system got a bit slow. I think this might have been due to that hardware access for the operating system can't be optimized since it needs to be kept general to run on different types of hardware. I would imagine that by doing a minimal installation for the virtual machine host on the laptop and the desktop the hardware access could be optimized by the virtual machine host software. The question is, it possible to run a hypervisor type 1 and guest os on the same computer?